# Magento 2: Change web site customer is registered to - will this cause issues?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, magento2.3.3

We have a Magento 2.3.3 store set up with multiple websites, each with different pricing and currency for different countries.

One of our customers has moved to a different country and wants the website they are registered to changed so that they can continue shopping with us but still have a history of past orders under their account.

I see that Magento 2 now allows for the customer website to be changed from the Customers panel.

Is this safe to do or are there any pitfalls we should be aware of?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is safe to do. But make sure if you are doing then at least you should take database backup for the safe side

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: No I don't have any source for this